# font color( I am new to this soz if it is basic)

Tags: css, colors, fonts, styles

I can't get the font color tag to work. where have I got wrong

```
<font="color:orange>
<! –– [lyrics] ––>

<p>

All my life, I've been walking on my own

<p>

Along the lonely road of the heart

<p>

On my side, I got symphonies and songs

<p>

To help me find my way through the dark

<p>

Oh, six in the morning with nowhere to go

<p>

Sing hello world, it feels so good to be home

<p>

Lost in the dark, but I'll never be alone

<p>

Sing hello world, it feels so good to be home

<p>

Hello, hello, hello world

<p>

I open my eyes and said hello to the world (hello to the world)

<p>

Hello, hello, hello world

<p>

I open my eyes and said hello to the world

<p>

All night long, I've been talking to myself

<p>

The voices in my head don't cry

<p>

On my mind, I become somebody else

<p>

So this is how it feels to say goodbye

<p>

Oh, six in the morning with nowhere to go

<p>

Sing hello world, it feels so good to be home

<p>

Lost in the dark, but I'll never be alone

<p>

Sing hello world, it feels so good to be home

<p>

Hello, hello, hello world

<p>

I open my eyes and said hello to the world (Hello to the world)

<p>

Hello, hello, hello world

<p>

(I open my eyes and said hello to the world)
<! –– [lyrics] ––>
</font\>
```

I tried a lot of things but can't get it to work(yes trail and error falled me)

Comment: Plase add your code correctly to your question, not as plain text. Preferably as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. For use of font as a tag see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font?msclkid=3d74904cb25711eca2e80283d9f0d97d You have the wrong format. But font tag is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for  many years.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, `<font>` tag is tag from HTML4 and isn't supported in HTML5 (you shouldn't use it).

If you want to change color of text, use `color` property in CSS. Here is your code:

```html
<p style="color: orange;">
   Here goes your lyrics...
</p>
```

I hope it was useful.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your answer**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I didn't know about that. I sometimes saw people that used JSFiddle in answers. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

if you have a separate CSS file just know your tag if its a paragraph or a heading tag and

```
h1 {
color: orange
}
```

and if you are trying to add inline CSS then add tag style like

```
<p style = "color: orange">
```

this also do the trick

Answer (score 1):

To set the color of your font, in the CSS file (or inline) you would want to use color. You should not use the font tag as it is no longer supported in HTML5.

```
p { color: blue }
```

This would set the color of all your p (paragraph tags) to blue.
To do this using inline CSS you would use the following snippet.

```
<p style="color: blue">Hello World</p>
```

With color, you can use color codes, or you can use the predefined CSS colors like blue, orange, and so on.